# Struggling creating a difference function

Tags: r, function, difference

So I have a homework problem that I am really struggling to code in R.

This is the problem: Write a function `difference()` that takes a vector X as a parameter and returns a vector of the 
difference between each element and the next element: 
`X[2]-X[1], X[3]-X[2], X[4]-X[3]`, etc.

Thus `difference(c(5,2,9,4,8))` would return `c(-3,7,-5,4)`

And so far I have this:

```
difference<-function(X) {
  for (i in X)
   X.val<-X[i]-X[i-1]
   return(X.val)
    }
difference(c(5,2,9,4,8))
```

I cant seem to get the function to subtract the `X[2]-X[1]` and it is returning one more number than it should when I run the function. Can anyone help me?

Comment: There is a ``diff`` function in ``base``. Try ``diff(c(5,2,9,4,8))``.

Comment: @user2728808 OP states it's a homework problem, so it's probably safe to assume they're not allowed to use `diff`.

Comment: @brittenb quite right, I missed that.

Comment: there is no need for loops here: hint: `hint, if 
X=c(5,2,9,4,8) ; X[2] - X[1] ;  X[2:3] - X[1:2]` . So try to find an appropriate way to index the vectors

Comment: Are you supposed to use a `for` loop? The function that you posted returns `X[8]-X[8-1]`, which is `NA`-`NA` and therefore `NA`. Is this really the function that you used, or did you miss something while posting? Note that it would be more R-like to use `c(2,9,4,8) - c(5,2,9,4)` instead of a for loop.

Comment: @lukeA It would be even more R-like to use `tail` - `head` to allow for any length vector.

Comment: I dont have to use a for loop its just the only thing I could think of

Comment: @brittenb Yes, I'd do `c(5,2,9,4,8)[-1]-head(c(5,2,9,4,8), -1)`. but I thought I'd better show it the approach in an easier way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're having a couple of problems with your code. Since this is homework, I'm not going to provide the correct code, but I'll help highlight where you're going wrong to help you get closer. The only reason I'm not providing the answer is because these are good learning experiences. If you comment with updated attempts, I'll continue to update my answer to guide you.

The issue is that you're using `for (i in X)`, which will actually loop through the values of `X` and not its index. So, in your example, `i` will equal 5 and then 2 and then 9 and then 4 and then 8. If we start with i == 5, the code is doing this: `X.val <- X[5] - X[5 - 1]`. At this point you'd assign `X.val` to be 4 because `X[5]` is equal to 8 and `X[4]` is equal to 4. At the next iteration, i == 2. So this will set `X.val` to -3 because `X[2]` is 2 and `X[1]` is 5.

To fix this issue, you'd want to loop through the index of `X` instead. You can do this by using `for (i in 1:length(X))` where `length(X)` will give you a number equal to the number of elements in `X`.

The next issue you've found is that you're getting one extra number. It's important to think about how many numbers you should have in your output and what this means in terms of where `i` should start. Hint: should you really be starting at 1?

Lastly, you overwrite `X.val` in each iteration. It surprises me that you were getting an extra number in your results given that you should have only received `NA` given that the last number is 8 and there are not 8 elements in `X`. Nevertheless, you'll need to rewrite your code so that you don't overwrite `X.val`, but instead append to it for each iteration.

I hope that helps.

### UPDATE #1

As noted in the comments below, your code now looks like this:

```
difference <- function(X) {
  for (i in 2:length(X)) {
    X[i] <- X[i] - X[i-1]
  }
  return(X)
}
difference(c(5, 2, 9, 4, 8))
```

We are now very, very close to a final solution. We just need to address a quick problem.

The problem is that we're now overriding our value of X, which is bad. Since our numbers, `c(5,2,9,4,8)`, are passed into the function as the variable `X`, the line `X[i] <- X[i] - X[i-1]` will start to override our values. So, stepping through one iteration at a time, we get the following:

Step 1:

- `i` gets set to 2
- `X[2]` is currently equal to 2
- We then run the line `X[i] <- X[i] - X[i-1]`, which gets evaluated like this: `X[2] <- X[2] - X[1]` --> `X[2] <- 2 - 5` --> `X[2] <- -3`
- `X[2]` is now set to -3

Step 2:

- `i` gets set to 3
- `X[3]` is currently equal to 9
- We then run the `X[i] <- X[i] - X[i-1]`, which gets evaluated like this: `X[3] <- X[3] - X[2]` --> `X[3] <- 9 - -3` --> `X[3] <- 12`
- `X[3]` is now set to 12

As you can see from the first two iterations, we're overwriting our `X` variable, which is directly impacting the differences we get when we run our function.

To solve this, we simply go back to using `X.val`, like we were before. Since this variable has no values, there's nothing to be overwritten. Our function now looks like this:

```
difference <- function(X) {
  for (i in 2:length(X)) {
    X.val[i] <- X[i] - X[i-1]
  }
  return(X.val)
}
```

Now, for each iteration, nothing is overwritten and our values of `X` stay in tact. There are two problems that we're going to have though. If we run this new code, we'll end up with an error telling us that `x.diff` doesn't exist. Earlier, I told you that you can index a variable that you're making, which is true. We just have to tell R that the variable we're making is a variable first. There are several ways to do this, but the second best way to do it is to create a variable with the same `class` as our expected output. Since we know we want our output to be a list of numbers, we can just make `X.val` a `numeric` vector. Our code now looks like this:

```
difference <- function(X) {
  X.val <- numeric()
  for (i in 2:length(X)) {
    X.val[i] <- X[i] - X[i-1]
  }
  return(X.val)
}
```

Notice that the assignment of `X.val` happens before we enter the `for` loop. As an exercise, you should think about why that's the case and then try moving it inside of the `for` loop and seeing what happens.

So this, solves our first problem. Try running the code and seeing what you get. You'll notice that the first element of the output is `NA`. Why might this be the case, and how can we fix it? Hint: it has to do with the value of `i`.

### UPDATE #2

So now that we have the correct answer, let's look at a couple tips and tricks that are available thanks to R. R has some inherent features that it can use on vectors. To see this action, run the following example:

```
a <- 1:10
b <- 11:20
a + b
a - b
a * b
a / b
```

As you can see, R will automatically perform what is called "element wise" operations for vectors. You'll notice that `a - b` is pretty similar to what we were trying to do here. The difference is that `a` and `b` are two different vectors and we were dealing with one vector at a time. So how do we set up our problem to work like this? Simple: we create two vectors.

```
x <- c(5, 2, 9, 4, 8)
y <- x[2:length(x)]
z <- x[1:(length(x)-1)]
y - z
```

You should notice that `y - z` now gives us the answer that we wanted from our function. We can apply that to our `difference` function like so:

```
difference <- function(X) {
  y <- X[2:length(X)]
  z <- X[1:(length(X)-1)]
  return(y-z)
}
```

Using this trick, we no longer need to use a `for` loop, which can be incredibly slow in R, and instead use the vectorized operation, which is incredibly fast in R. As was stated in the comments, we can actually skip the step of assignin those values to `y` and `z` and can instead just directly return what we want:

```
difference <- function(X) {
  return(X[2:length(X)] - X[1:(length(X)-1)])
}
```

We've now just successfully created a one-line function that does what we were hoping to do. Let's see if we can make it even cleaner. R comes with two functions that are very handy for looking at data: `head()` and `tail()`. `head` allows you to look at the first n number of elements and `tail` allows you to look at the last n number of elements. Let's see an example.

```
a <- 1:50
head(a) # defaults to 6 elements
tail(a) # defaults to 6 elements
head(a, n=20) # we can change how many elements to return
tail(a, n=20)
head(a, n=-1) # returns all but the last element
tail(a, n=-1) # returns all but the first element
```

Those last two are the most important for what we want to do. In our newest version of `difference` we were looking at `X[2:length(X)]`, which is another way of saying "all elements in `X` except the first element". We were also looking at `X[1:(length(X)-1)]`, which is another way of saying "all elements in `X` except the last element". Let's clean that up:

```
difference <- function(X) {
  return(tail(X, -1) - head(X, -1))
}
```

As you can see, that's a much cleaner way of defining our function.

So those are the tricks. Let's look at a couple tips. The first is to drop the `return` from simple functions like this. R will automatically return the last command if a function if it's not an assignment. To see this in action, try running the two different functions:

```
difference_1 <- function(X) {
  x.diff <- tail(X, -1) - head(X, -1)
}
difference_1(1:10)

difference_2 <- function(X) {
  tail(X, -1) - head(X, -1)
}
difference_2(1:10)
```

In `difference_1` you'll notice that nothing is returned. This is because the command is an assignment command. You could force it to return a value by using the `return` command.

The next tip is something you won't need for a while, but it's important. Going back to the current version of `difference` that we have (the code you're using now, not anything I've mentioned in this update), we assign values to `X.val`, which causes it to "grow" over time. To see what this means, run the following code:

```
x.val <- numeric()
length(x)

x.val[1] <- 1
length(x)

x.val[2] <- 2
length(x)
```

You'll see that the length keeps growing. This is often a point of **huge** slowdowns in R code. The proper way to do this is to create `x.val` with a length equal to how big we need it. This is much, much faster and will save you some pains in the future. Here's how it would work:

```
difference <- function(X) {
  x.val <- numeric(length=(length(X) - 1))
  for (i in 2:length(X)) {
    x.val[i-1] <- X[i] - X[i-1]
  }
  return(x.val)
}
```

In our current code, this doesn't make a real difference. But if you're dealing with very large data in the future, this can you hours or even days of computing time.

I hope this all helps you better understand some of the functionality in R. Good luck with everything!

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me, I am completely new to R or any programming software so this is all incredibly confusing for me. This is what I have got:

        difference<-function(X) {
  for (i in 2:length(X))
  X.val<-X[2:length(X)]-X[1:length(X)]
  return(X.val)
}
difference(c(5,2,9,4,8))

but this is what Im getting back
[1] -3  7 -5  4 -6
Warning messages:
1: In X[2:length(X)] - X[1:length(X)] :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

So I have the correct numbers but still an extra number and the warning messages

Comment: Your solution is getting much closer. Given that you're new programming in general, I would recommend going back to your `X[i] - X[i-1]` approach. The comments above focus on efficiency and writing code in "R fashion". That's important to learn, but you shouldn't focus on it right now. You correctly changed the index in your `for` loop, so nice work on that! Next, you should try to figure out how to add each value of `X[i] - X[i-1]` to `X.val`.

Comment: Hint: you can index a variable that you're creating the same way you can index a variable you've already made. For example, `X.val[i]` is valid.

Comment: I am still having a really hard time. THis is what I have:
        difference<-function(X) {
  for (i in 2:length(X))  {
    X[i]<-X[i]-X[i-1]
    return(X)
  }
}
difference(c(5,2,9,4,8))


but now it is not returning any of the correct answers.

Comment: @Natalie please see my updated response that addresses the issues you're having. Again, I haven't fully answered the question, but instead provided guidance.

Comment: I think I got it!

        difference <- function(X) {
  X.val <- numeric()
  for (i in 2:length(X)) {
    X.val[i-1] <- X[i] - X[i-1]
  }
  return(X.val)
}
difference(c(5,2,9,4,8))

I needed X.val to not reference the first element in the index right? Thank you so much for all of your help!

Comment: @Natalie Correct! I'm glad I could help. I've updated my answer a second time to review a couple tips and tricks, some of which were mentioned in the comments above.